# Comparism of Date and time to find long flights

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, where-clause

Hello I am using Sqlite and fairly new to this and this is the query

"Using the Airline DB, write a query that selects all rows from the flight table where the flight's duration is greater than 24 hours.

Hint: use datetime(...,"+24 hours") and a comparison"

select *
from flight
where  datetime ('departure', '+24 hours')

This is my query which shows up zero results. I don't understand what I am suppose to compare when all I am trying to do is found out if any plane has a 24 hour flight time.

[Flight Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyhSa.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select * 
from flight 
where arrival > datetime (departure, '+24 hours')
```

Expression `datetime (departure, '+24 hours')` adds 24 hours to the departure date (note that I removed the single quotes around the column name - otherwise it becomes a literal string). We can then check if the arrival date is greater than that, which indicates that the flight lasts more than 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're a life saver. I just did not understand what comparison they were talking about.